Navigator not defined
I am working on a streaming project using Reactjs and Nodejs. I use peerjs and Webrtc for the streaming function and constantly having issue with: Navigator is not defined.
I am not sure how to fix it.
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: "/",
    port: "3002",
});

const streamBlock = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const room = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    const myVid = document.createElement('video');
    myVid.muted = true;
 
    myPeer.on('open', id => {
    socket.emit('join-room', room, id)
    console.log(room);
})

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
}).then(stream => {
    addStream(myVid, stream)

    myPeer.on('call', call => {
    call.answer(stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userStream => {
        addStream(video, userStream)
    })
    })
})
 }
})
 
const addStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
})
streamBlock.current.append(video)
}


It would appear this is executing on the server-side, but you are expecting a client-side object (navigator). Navigator is not part of Node.js, but is a part of the browser.
I'd recommend ensuring the above code is not running on your server but is instead being served up to the client. Maybe using something like useEffect() or embedding it in the component that will call it when an action is triggered.
